# La Clojure Repl set java.library.path for dll

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, la-clojure

Would like to use the La Clojure Repl with jacob. So I need to set

```
-Djava.library.path=D:/opensource/jacob-1.17-M2
```

Cannot find this for the REPL

Comment: Second this. I'm unable to experiment with ZeroMQ from inside my Clojure REPL. Looks like I cannot do this with leiningen too...

Comment: Is this question about the "Clojure Console?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Add Facet "Clojure". You should now be able to edit the "JVM Arguments" for the REPL

Comment: This gave me the info to solve my similar issue. I went to "Edit Configurations" -> "VM Options" and pasted the parameter declaration there. (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-application.html)